# How to cancel a running animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a number of animations that I'm using jQuery to animate. Each event might be made up of  a number of animations chained together. I only want one to run at a time but if a new event occurs I want to leave the current event and go to the new one. example:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="div1"></div>
    <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
<button class="btn">Click me</button>
```

CSS:

```css
.container {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    background: yellow;   
    position: relative;
}
.div1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    width: 90px;
    height: 80px;
    background: red;
    opacity: 0
}
.div2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 90px;
    top: 10px;
    width: 90px;
    height: 80px;
    background: green;
    opacity: 0
}
```

jQuery:

```
var count = 1, element;
$('.btn').click(function() {
    if (element) {
        element.stop();
    }
    element = $('.div' + count);
    count = count === 1 ? 2 : 1;
    element.animate({opacity:1}, 1000, function(){
        element.animate({left: '50px'}, 2000, function() {
            element.animate({opacity: 0}, 1000, function(){
                element.removeAttr('style');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

The jQuery docs mention this stop() method that should cancel the animation but it's not working in this example. [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/r68vmL86/3/)

Comment: you're not assigning any value to the element variable it is undefined for the if statement

Comment: sorry, my bad, I've edited the code and the fiddle. Same problem applies

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem. It appears to be working fine. Can you please explain what you expect to happen more clearly?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/r68vmL86/4/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by adding:

```
            element.removeAttr('style');
            element = undefined;
```

to the if statement checking for element. I guess that the stop() would stop the currently running animation but not the next in the chain. Thanks for the input

C

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
element.stop(false, true);
```